# Suppressing Method Return in Object Oriented Language

Tags: oop, syntax, constructor, syntactic-sugar

I'm going to preface this by saying that this is by no means a major issue, more of something I haven't really heard talked about in terms of programming language design, and I was wondering if anyone had any interesting solutions.

The crux of the problem is this. Sometimes in an object-oriented language, I want to be able to modify an object via one of its methods, but **return the object itself** instead of what that method returns.

to give a java example:

```
class MyClass{
    public MyClass(List<Integer> list){
        //do constructor stuff
    }

    public MyClass(Integer i){
        //what I would like to be able to do
        this((new LinkedList<Integer>).add(i));
    }
}
```

I can't create a temporary list in the second constructor, because this() must be the first line. Obviously there are a lot of ways to do this by changing the implementation, like creating an add() method that returns the object, making it the responsibility of the function constructing the object to make the list, etc.

But, considering a lot of the time you can't/don't want to modify or create a subclass (for LinkedList) and you might not want to muddy up the calling code, being able to modify and return an object in the style of ++x could be really useful. Something like
`this(#(new LinkedList).add(i)` to signify you want to object, not the method return. Does anyone know of a language that allows this is some concise syntactic way? If not, would this be useful at all or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to understand in terms of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @AndrasK Were any of the answers acceptable?

Comment: The crux of what I'd like to achieve would be a clean way to modify anonymous objects through their methods. It's possible to do this by having all method of a class return themselves, but this isn't really "clean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(List<Integer> list){
        //do constructor stuff
    }

    public static MyClass create(Integer i) {
        List<Integer> list = new new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(i);
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(list);
        return myClass;
    }
}
```

This is somewhat common design pattern called [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to solve this is to have an initialize method called from the constructors.

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(List list){
        init(list);
    }

```
public MyClass(Integer i){
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add(i);
    init(list);
}

protected init(List<Integer> list)
{
    // do init stuff here
}
```

}